# protocol violation when using angular $resource.save()

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs

I have a hybrid ASP.NET MVC view page that has an angular controller that uses $resource's save() and delete() methods in factories as code snips below.  The controller's delete() method works. When the add() is executed, Fiddler shows a status of 201(Created), and the new user is added to the database, but the IE F12 console shows the following [$resource:badcfg] error. Neither the success or failure callback is executed. No alert nor screen refresh.  For your reference, I added the post() action of the WebAPI with which the Angular $resource work.  I also modified the $resource action parameter to set the isArray to false.  I still get the same [$resource:badcfg] error. Is there something in the return result that is not expected by Angular? Thanks for your help.

```html
[$resource:badcfg] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.6/$resource/badcfg?p0=save&p1=object&p2=array&p3=POST&p4=http%3A%2F%2FmyIISServerName%3A8083%2FWCF_WebAPI%2FCMT%2Fapi%2FuserFSR%2Fadd%2F129%2F1540
```

```js
ufsrApp.factory('userFsrAddFactory', ['$resource',
  function($resource) {
    return $resource(userFsrURI + 'userFSR/add/:userId/:fsrId', {
      userId: '@userId',
      fsrId: '@fsrId'
    },     
    {
      save: {method: 'POST', isArray: false}
    });
  }
])

ufsrApp.factory('userFsrDeleteFactory', ['$resource',
  function($resource) {
    return $resource(userFsrURI + 'userFSR/delete/:userId/:ufsrId'
      //,
      //  { userId: '@userId', ufsrId: '@ufsrId' }
    );
  }
])

ufsrApp.controller('ufsrController', [...omitted for brevity... ,
      function(....omitted for brevity....) {

        $scope.add = function() {
          $scope.newUserFSR = new userFsrAddFactory();
          $scope.newUserFSR.userId = $scope.userId;
          $scope.newUserFSR.fsrId = $scope.role;
          userFsrAddFactory.save($scope.newUserFSR,
            function() { //success callback
              alert("New role added");
              $scope.postStatus = true;
              //using jquery location object to reload the page after adding a new user
              location.reload(true); 
            },
            function() { //failure callback
              alert("add role failed");
              $scope.postStatus = false;
            }
          );

        }

  }]);
```

The following is the Post() of the WebAPI the Angular controller is posting to.

```js
     /// <summary>
     /// create new user FSR
     /// </summary>
     /// <param name="userId"></param>
     /// <param name="fsrId"></param>
     /// <returns></returns>
    [Route("add/{userId:int}/{fsrId:int}")]
     public async Task < HttpResponseMessage > Post(int userId, int fsrId) {
      try {
        var userFSR = await repo.GetUserFSR(userId);
        if (userFSR == null)
          return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        else {
          int newKey = await repo.PostUserFSR(userId, fsrId);

          return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, userFSR);;
        }
      } catch (Exception ex) {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out the problem.  It turned that my WebAPI post method return a userFSR object in addition to the Create (201) status.  So I modified my code snip above to this:

**return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created);**

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> //using jquery location object to reload the page after adding a new user
> location.reload(true);
> ```

If that's what you want to do, you should make your code actually do that. What you have now runs after you call `save()`, but before the request to the server has received a response, and possibly even before the request has been fully sent to the server (causing the error you see).

This should go into your success callback instead. Or just don't reload at all -- you should easily be able to make things work without reloading.

Comment: Yes, I tried to put the reload code in the success callback block, but it just doesn't get called even after the server successfully save the record to the database.

Comment: @user266909 Did you check that the server actually reports success? Without seeing the code, my first guess would be that it saves the record to the database, and then returns an error anyway for some reason.

Comment: I moved the location.reload(true) into the success callback block.  When executed the save() method, IE console shows "[$resource:badcfg] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.6/$resource/badcfg?p0=save&p1=object&p2=array&p3=POST&p4=http%3A%2F%2FmyIISServerName%3A8083%2FWCF_WebAPI%2FCMT%2Fapi%2FuserFSR%2Fadd%2F129%2F205"

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Yes, according to Fiddler, the return status code is 201.  I manually refreshed the page with F5 in IE, the new user is listed in a table.

Comment: @user266909 Ah right, you did mention the status code already. But that error still shows that your service is not set up correctly, doesn't it? It shows that there is a difference between what your AngularJS service expects your web service to return, and what your web service actually returns. Solve that problem, get rid of that error, and your success callback will run. The default for `save` is that it expects a response that can be seen as an object, but instead you're returning something that gets seen as an array.